# Bing Maps Control China

Tags: windows-phone-7, submit, bing-maps, app-hub

I was trying to upload my wp7 application to the marketplace, and it failed with the following comment:

"Your application uses the Bing Maps Silverlight Control for Windows Phone. Bing Maps is not supported for
Group 1 countries at this time. You may resubmit your application and deselect the Group 1 countries."

Group 1: China.

I do not wan't to deselect China, is there some kind other control that I could use so that I can publish my app there?

Or any other solution would be good!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at this post. 
http://damianblog.com/2012/06/20/windowsphone-different-builds-different-markets/

i have come across many who had this issue.. looks like marketplace policy issue here

Comment: seems like a good solution, I will consider and mark this as an answer. Thank you!